# How to safely call an async method in C# without await

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have an `async` method which returns no data:

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // do some stuff async, don't return any data
}
```

I'm calling this from another method which returns some data:

```
public string GetStringData()
{
    MyAsyncMethod(); // this generates a warning and swallows exceptions
    return "hello world";
}
```

Calling `MyAsyncMethod()` without awaiting it causes a "[Because this call is not awaited, the current method continues to run before the call is completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh965065.aspx)" warning in visual studio. On the page for that warning it states:

> You should consider suppressing the warning only if you're sure that you don't want to wait for the asynchronous call to complete and that **the called method won't raise any exceptions**.

I'm sure I don't want to wait for the call to complete; I don't need to or have the time to. **But the call *might* raise exceptions.**

I've stumbled into this problem a few times and I'm sure it's a common problem which must have a common solution.

**How do I safely call an async method without awaiting the result?**

## Update:

For people suggesting that I just await the result, this is code that is responding to a web request on our web service (ASP.NET Web API). Awaiting in a UI context keeps the UI thread free, but awaiting in a web request call will wait for the Task to finish before responding to the request, thereby increasing response times with no reason.

Comment: Why not just create a completion method and just ignore it there? Because if it is running on background thread. Then it won't stop your program from terminating anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the result, the only option is to ignore/suppress the warning.  If you *do* want to wait for the result/exception then `MyAsyncMethod().Wait()`

Comment: About your edit: that does not make sense to me. Say the response is sent to the client 1 sec after the request, and 2 secs later your async method throws an exception. What would you do with that exception? You cannot send it to the client, if your response is already sent. What else would you do with it?

Comment: @Romoku Fair enough. Assuming someone looks at the log, anyway. :)

Comment: A variation on the ASP.NET Web API scenario is a *self-hosted* Web API in a long-lived process (like, say, a Windows service), where a request creates a lengthy background task to do something expensive, but still wants to get a response quickly with an HTTP 202 (Accepted).

Comment: Why not use `Task.Run()`?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

If you want to get the exception "asynchronously", you could do:

```
  MyAsyncMethod().
    ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

This will allow you to deal with an exception on a thread other than the "main" thread.  This means you don't have to "wait" for the call to `MyAsyncMethod()` from the thread that calls `MyAsyncMethod`; but, still allows you  to do something with an exception--but only if an exception occurs.

## Update:

technically, you could do something similar with `await`:

```
try
{
    await MyAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

...which would be useful if you needed to specifically use `try`/`catch` (or `using`) but I find the `ContinueWith` to be a little more explicit because you have to know what [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) means.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer but also see my answer below and Stephen Cleary's point specific to doing this in ASP.NET

Comment: Note that neither ContiuneWith nor ConfigureAwait seem to be available in WinRT

Comment: I turned this into an extension method on `Task`:
    public static class AsyncUtility
    {
        public static void PerformAsyncTaskWithoutAwait(this Task task, Action<Task> exceptionHandler)
        {
            var dummy = task.ContinueWith(t => exceptionHandler(t), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
    }

Usage:
MyAsyncMethod().PerformAsyncTaskWithoutAwait(t => log.ErrorFormat("An error occurred while calling MyAsyncMethod:\n{0}", t.Exception));

Comment: downvoter.  Comments?  If there's something wrong in the answer, I'd love to know and/or fix.

Comment: Hey - I did not downvote, but... Can you explain your update? The call was not supposed to be awaited, so if you do it like that, then you do wait for the call, you just don't continue on the captured context...

Comment: "wait" isn't the correct description in this context.  The line after the `ConfiguratAwait(false)` doesn't execute until the task completes, but the current thread doesn't "wait" (i.e. block) for that, the next line is called asynchronously to the await invocation.  Without the `ConfigureAwait(false)` that next line would be executed on the original web request context.  With the `ConfigurateAwait(false)` it's executed in the same context as the async method (task), freeing the original context/thread to continue on...

Comment: The ContinueWith version is not the same as the try{ await }catch{} version. In the first version, everything after ContinueWith() will execute immediately. The initial task is fired and forgotten. In the second version, everything after the catch{} will execute only after the initial task is completed. The second version is equivalent to "await  MyAsyncMethod().ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).ConfigureAwait(fals);

Comment: I tried a test app with `.ConfigureAwait(false);` but it still suspends a loop. The only solution I found was to make the called method `async void` (so no await is required), which solution everyone considers bad. But I think it's the nicest solution for creating an independent task.

Comment: Confirmed that the comment from Thanasis Ioannidis is best to answer the OP question. @PeterRitchie, I strongly recommend updating your accepted answer to avoid this being buried in comments.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten you could change the return type of your async method to `async Task`, that is essentially the same as `async void` but gives you more control over the actual, well, task.

Comment: @thebugsdontwork I don't seem to have any posts for this thread. Did you write the question to the correct place?

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(false);` is still awaited. `.ConfigureAwait(false);` give a hint that when the async method finishes, it dos not need to return to the same "Thread", but can continue in any Thread.

Answer (score 105):

You should first consider making `GetStringData` an `async` method and have it `await` the task returned from `MyAsyncMethod`.

If you're absolutely sure that you don't need to handle exceptions from `MyAsyncMethod` *or* know when it completes, then you can do this:

```
public string GetStringData()
{
  var _ = MyAsyncMethod();
  return "hello world";
}
```

BTW, this is not a "common problem". It's very rare to want to execute some code and not care whether it completes *and* not care whether it completes successfully.

**Update:**

Since you're on ASP.NET and wanting to return early, you may find my [blog post on the subject useful](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html). However, ASP.NET was not designed for this, and there's no *guarantee* that your code will run after the response is returned. ASP.NET will do its best to let it run, but it can't guarantee it.

So, this is a fine solution for something simple like tossing an event into a log where it doesn't *really* matter if you lose a few here and there. It's not a good solution for any kind of business-critical operations. In those situations, you *must* adopt a more complex architecture, with a persistent way to save the operations (e.g., Azure Queues, MSMQ) and a separate background process (e.g., Azure Worker Role, Win32 Service) to process them.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. I **do** care if it throws exceptions and fails, but I don't want to have to await the method before returning my data. Also see my edit about the context I'm working in if that makes any difference.

Comment: @GeorgePowell: It's very dangerous to have code running in an ASP.NET context without an active request. I have a [blog post that may help you out](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html), but without knowing more of your problem I can't say whether I'd recommend that approach or not.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have a similar need. In my example, I have/need a batch processing engine to run in the cloud, I'll "ping" the end point to kick off batch processing, but I want to return immediately. Since pinging it gets it started, it can handle everything from there. If there are exceptions that are thrown, then they'd just be logged in my "BatchProcessLog/Error" tables...

Comment: In C#7, you can replace `var _ = MyAsyncMethod();` with `_ = MyAsyncMethod();`.  This still avoids warning CS4014, but it makes it a bit more explicit that you're not using the variable.

Comment: I think what OP means is that he doesn't want the client (HTTP Request) to wait on whether logging something to a database succeeds. If the logging fails, sure the application should still have full control over handling that exception, but we don't need the client to wait around for the handling of that. I think what that means is that work needs to be done on a background thread. Yeah.. sucks to reserve a thread to do an async task, but it needs to be done to handle potential exceptions.

Answer (score 65):

The answer by Peter Ritchie was what I wanted, and [Stephen Cleary's article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) about returning early in ASP.NET was very helpful.

As a more general problem however (not specific to an ASP.NET context) the following Console application demonstrates the usage and behavior of Peter's answer using `Task.ContinueWith(...)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    // output "hello world" as method returns early
    Console.WriteLine(GetStringData());
  }
  catch
  {
    // Exception is NOT caught here
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string GetStringData()
{
  MyAsyncMethod().ContinueWith(OnMyAsyncMethodFailed, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
  return "hello world";
}

public static async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
  await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("thrown on background thread"); });
}

public static void OnMyAsyncMethodFailed(Task task)
{
  Exception ex = task.Exception;
  // Deal with exceptions here however you want
}
```

`GetStringData()` returns early without awaiting `MyAsyncMethod()` and exceptions thrown in `MyAsyncMethod()` are dealt with in `OnMyAsyncMethodFailed(Task task)` and **not** in the `try`/`catch` around `GetStringData()`

Comment: Remove `Console.ReadLine();` and add a little sleep/delay in `MyAsyncMethod` and you'll never see the exception.

Answer (score 28):

I end up with this solution :

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // do some stuff async, don't return any data
}

public string GetStringData()
{
    // Run async, no warning, exception are catched
    RunAsync(MyAsyncMethod()); 
    return "hello world";
}

private void RunAsync(Task task)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ILog log = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILog>();
        log.Error("Unexpected Error", t.Exception);

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Answer (score 24):

This is called fire and forget, and there is an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.tplextensions.forget?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) for that.

> Consumes a task and doesn't do anything with it. Useful for fire-and-forget calls to async methods within async methods.

Install [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/).

Use:

```
MyAsyncMethod().Forget();
```

EDIT: There is [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048102/c-sharp-fire-and-forget-task-and-discard) I've been rather using lately:

```
_ = MyAsyncMethod();
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it's just a trick to remove the warning. See https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/TplExtensions.cs#L256

Comment: Correction: It does a bunch of stuff to avoid reacting to the call that was made.

Answer (score 15):

Not the best practice, you should try avoiding this.

However, just to address "Call an async method in C# without await", you can execute the async method inside a `Task.Run`. This approach will wait until `MyAsyncMethod` finish.

```
public string GetStringData()
{
    Task.Run(()=> MyAsyncMethod()).Result;
    return "hello world";
}
```

`await` asynchronously unwraps the `Result` of your task, whereas just using **Result** would block until the task had completed.

If you want to wrap it in a helper class:

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    public static void Sync(Func<Task> func) => Task.Run(func).ConfigureAwait(false);

    public static T Sync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func) => Task.Run(func).Result;

}
```

and call like

```
public string GetStringData()
{
    AsyncHelper.Sync(() => MyAsyncMethod());
    return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `MyAsyncMethod().Result` just do the same thing?

Answer (score 10):

I'm late to the party here, but there's an awesome library I've been using which I haven't seen referenced in the other answers

https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices

If you need to "Fire And Forget" you call the extension method on the task.

Passing the action onException to the call ensures that you get the best of both worlds - no need to await execution and slow your users down, whilst retaining the ability to handle the exception in a graceful manner.

In your example you would use it like this:

```
   public string GetStringData()
    {
        MyAsyncMethod().SafeFireAndForget(onException: (exception) =>
                    {
                      //DO STUFF WITH THE EXCEPTION                    
                    }); 
        return "hello world";
    }
```

It also gives awaitable AsyncCommands implementing ICommand out the box which is great for my MVVM Xamarin solution

Comment: This doesn't add confidence to it? https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/issues/65

Comment: The author of that post is using purposefully bad design by using Thread.Sleep inside of his BadTask instead of await Task.Delay. (I'm not sure why). In almost all normal cases, you wouldn't do this. For most use cases, this does what it says on the tin.

Comment: @AdamDiament they're using `Thread.Sleep` to simulate a task that does a large amount of synchronous work before `await`ing something (e.g. if you had to do a computationally expensive calculation before sending the result to an api), and they're pointing out that if the initial synchronous part of the task takes a long time or throws an exception then so will the caller, so it's not really a "safe" fire & forget

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question arises, why would you need to do this? The reason for `async` in C# 5.0 is so you can await a result. This method is not actually asynchronous, but simply called at a time so as not to interfere too much with the current thread.

Perhaps it may be better to start a thread and leave it to finish on its own.

Comment: `async` is a bit more than just "awaiting" a result.  "await" implies that the lines following "await" are executed asynchronously on the same thread that invoked "await".  This can be done without "await", of course, but you end up having a bunch of delegates and lose the sequential look-and-feel of the code (as well as the ability to use `using` and `try/catch`...

Comment: @PeterRitchie You can have a method that is functionally asynchronous, doesn't use the `await` keyword, and doesn't use the `async` keyword, but there is no point whatsoever in using the `async` keyword without also using `await` in the definition of that method.

Comment: @Servy yes, of course.  I'm not sure why you'd think I implied something different.

Comment: @PeterRitchie From the statement: "`async` is a bit more than just "awaiting" a result."  The `async` keyword (you implied it's the keyword by enclosing it in backticks) means *nothing* more than awaiting the result.  It's asynchrony, as the general CS concepts, that means more than just awaiting a result.

Comment: @Servy `async` creates a state machine that manages any awaits within the async method.  If there are no `await`s within the method it still creates that state machine--but the method is not asynchronous.  And if the `async` method returns `void`, there's nothing to await.  So, it's *more* than just awaiting a result.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Are you sure that the state machine is actually created when the method has no `await` calls in it?  They already introduce the compiler warning, so they know when it's the case.  I know if I were the compiler I wouldn't bother generating the state machine as you know it won't ever be leveraged.

Comment: @Servy Yep (I've reflected it many times), that's why you get the CS1998 warning.  You could do `async Task Method()` (and no `await`s in `Method`) and then `await Method()`.  Without the state machine, you couldn't `await` on `Method`.  I supose future expansion, virtual method, extension, etc...

Comment: @PeterRitchie As long as the method returns a task you can await it.  There is no need for the state machine, or the `async` keyword.  All you'd need to do (and all that really happens in the end with a state machine in that special case) is that the method is run synchronously and then wrapped in a completed task.  I suppose technically you don't just remove the state machine; you remove the state machine and then call `Task.FromResult`.  I assumed you (and also the compiler writers) could add the addendum on your own.

Answer (score 1):

On technologies with message loops (not sure if ASP is one of them), you can block the loop and process messages until the task is over, and use ContinueWith to unblock the code:

```
public void WaitForTask(Task task)
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    task.ContinueWith(t => frame.Continue = false));
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

This approach is similar to blocking on ShowDialog and still keeping the UI responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Typically async method returns Task class. If you use `Wait()` method or `Result` property and code throws exception - exception type gets wrapped up into `AggregateException` - then you need to query `Exception.InnerException` to locate correct exception.

But it's also possible to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead -
it will also wait async task, but will not wrap exception.

So here is short example:

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
}

public string GetStringData()
{
    MyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return "test";
}
```

You might want also to be able to return some parameter from async function - that can be achieved by providing extra `Action<return type>` into async function, for example like this:

```
public string GetStringData()
{
    return MyMethodWithReturnParameterAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task<String> MyMethodWithReturnParameterAsync()
{
    return "test";
}
```

Please note that async methods typically have `ASync` suffix naming, just to be able to avoid collision between sync functions with same name. (E.g. `FileStream.ReadAsync`) - I have updated function names to follow this recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I'm too naive but, couldn't you create an event that is raised when GetStringData() is called and attach an EventHandler that calls and awaits the async method?

Something like:

```cs
public event EventHandler FireAsync;

public string GetStringData()
{
   FireAsync?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   return "hello world";
}

public async void HandleFireAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await MyAsyncMethod();
}
```

And somewhere in the code attach and detach from the event:

```cs
FireAsync += HandleFireAsync;

(...)

FireAsync -= HandleFireAsync;
```

Not sure if this might be anti-pattern somehow (if it is please let me know), but it catches the Exceptions and returns quickly from GetStringData().

Comment: This is just an overly convoluted way of converting an asynchronous method to `async void`, so that the behavior is changed from fire-and-forget to fire-and-crash. You can achieve the same thing in a straightforward manner like this: `async void OnErrorCrash(this Task task) => await task;`

Answer (score -3):

The solution is start the HttpClient into another execution task without sincronization context:

```
var submit = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
var t = Task.Run(() => submit.ConfigureAwait(false));
await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score -3):

It is straightforward, just call asyncMethod().Result to call without await.   Below is the sample code and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4sRBmc) is the fiddle

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var asyncDemo = new AsyncDemo();
        asyncDemo.TestMethod1Void().Wait();
        var result = asyncDemo.TestMethod1().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public class AsyncDemo {
    
    public async Task<string> TestMethod1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return  "From Async Method";        
    }
    
    public async Task TestMethod1Void()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Async Void Method");     
    }
}
```