# Compiler warning CS4014 not emitted during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

Compiler warning CS4014 (calling async method without awaiting result) is not emitted as a warning during build when the called method is in a referenced assembly.

When the called method is in the *same* assembly the warning is correctly emitted.

The compiler warning *is* signaled in Visual Studio when both projects are contained in the same solution.

The difference seems to be caused by the compiler having only the compiled referenced assembly and Visual Studio having the source code to both assemblies.

The question is: why have these two different behaviors? And is there any way to have the CS4014 warning emitted during compilation?

To replicate this behavior setup two class libraries, both having one code file:

**TestClassLibrary1**

```
public class Class1
{
    public static async Task<string> DoSomething()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult("test");
    }
}
```

**TestClassLibrary2** (referencing TestClassLibrary1)

```
public class Class2
{
    public void CallingDoSomething()
    {
        Class1.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Compiling these projects will complete without warnings. Opening them in the same solution in Visual Studio will result in 1 error being shown in the Error List and a red squiggly line under `Class1.DoSomething()`.

Comment: How do you compile the assemblies? Can you show the statements you are using?

Comment: I'm compiling the assemblies using Visual Studio -> Build Solution. Both projects are compiled with all warnings on (`/warn:4`). If it would help I could paste in the arguments to csc.exe but those are quite long.

Comment: Okay, I thought you were running a build by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `async` modifier allows you to write code that returns a `Task` more conveniently (with `await`), but it has no representation in IL<sup>*</sup>. In a compiled assembly, the method simply looks like `public static Task<string> DoSomething` to the compiler, and calling those without awaiting their result doesn't trigger the warning (even if the methods live in the same assembly). Replace `Class1.DoSomething` with something else that returns a task and ought to be awaited (say `Task.Delay(2000)`) and you'll likewise see the compiler doesn't warn. When all of the source code is available, however, the compiler (and by compiler I mean Roslyn) can identify the method as `async` because the modifier is still part of the syntax tree.

So why doesn't the compiler just always warn when you call a method returning a `Task` without using the result, regardless of whether it happened to be written using `async`? Good question. While there are plenty of legitimate scenarios where you don't wait to await a `Task` (because you want to pass it to `Task.WhenAll` for example) all of these involve storing the `Task` somewhere else, which would not raise the warning. Calling a method that returns a `Task` and discarding the result entirely is almost certainly a mistake (and when it's intentional, there are [elegant ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629951/suppressing-warning-cs4014-because-this-call-is-not-awaited-execution-of-the#22630057) of suppressing the warning), which is why this warning exists in the first place.

I suspect the implementation of this warning could use a tweak (or a replacement with a new warning), but only the people working on the compiler would know that for sure.

---

*: this isn't actually true; `async` methods have an `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` applied to them for more convenient debugging. But, for whatever reason, the compiler doesn't use this to identify `async` methods across assemblies. Nor should it, arguably: there's nothing particularly special about `async` in terms of the `Task` the method returns. But if they wanted to preserve the stated semantics of CS4104 exactly (warn if the result of an `async` method is unused) this would be one way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps the prevalence of `Task.Run()` for launching fire-and-forget tasks means that the false positive rate would be too high to make the warning unconditional.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I have been working with a library called MassTransit that uses a pattern where it stores a Task internally and returns the same task. The caller has two options: 1. await the returned Task to make sure the operation completes correctly or 2. let MassTransit await the Task and handle any exceptions. So there might be legitimate uses of calling methods without awaiting.

Would raising an issue on the Roslyn GitHub repo help?

Comment: @BenjaminWegman: that usage pattern might be better served by offering two methods, one that returns the task and one that doesn't. But if you're stuck with that interface, a `.Forget()` extension method that discards the task deliberately as in the linked answer might be worthwhile. As for raising an issue on Roslyn, I'm not involved in the project at all so I don't know the bug culture. In that sense I'm not qualified to make any statement what "helps".