# Can you decorate a .Net method instead of using a #pragma to suppress a compiler warning?

Tags: c#

In my C# code I sometimes use a `#pragma` to suppress compiler warnings. For example without the pragma this code would give a compiler warning:

```
#pragma warning disable CS1998
    public virtual async Task Initialize()
    {
        StartLogging(true, true);
    }
#pragma warning restore CS1998
```

I seem to remember that there is a way to do this by decorating the method with an attribute instead of using the `#pragma` but I cannot find the documentation. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822330/575530) to another question Fábio shows the technique:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Await.Warning", "CS4014:Await.Warning")]
static async Task StartWorkAsync()
{
    WorkAsync();
}
```

He goes on to note that

> The important part of this code is the second parameter. The "CS4014:" part is what suppresses the warning. You can write anything you want on the rest.

The documentation for the SuppressMessageAttribute class is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and there is an overview of 
in source suppression [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx)