# How can I have both "fire-and-forget" and "guaranteed finish" in .Net Core MVC

Tags: async-await, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my MVC app, I have an **async** method that I need to call but don't want to wait. I don't care about the exception either because my logging framework will catch and log that.  I'm doing this now:

```
_ = auditService.AuditAsync(auditData);
```

What happens when my main http request is done but my audit service hasn't accepted my audit request (slow network)? I don't want to wait but I want it to finish. Is that possible to have both "fire and forget" and "guaranteed to finish"?

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630057/879655), ASP.NET may throw an exception. Is this still the case in Net Core?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018610/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864367/fire-and-forget-approach). My question is about whether ASP.NET will give me error on my way to call my async method.

Answer (score 0):

In Net Core (tested with 2.0) this seems OK. My sample code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEmail([FromServices] ILogger<EmailsController> logger )
{
    logger.LogInformation("Calling A()...");
    A(logger);
    logger.LogInformation("Done calling A()");
    return Ok(string.Empty);
}

async Task A(ILogger<EmailsController> logger)
{
    logger.LogInformation("A(). entered");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    logger.LogInformation("A(). working");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    logger.LogInformation("A(). working");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    logger.LogInformation("A() done. but ready to throw exception");
    // just to confirm that any exception in this method will be lost if we don't wait
    throw new Exception("Exception from A()");
}
```

I got 200 status back. No exception from ASP.NET. From log:

[image: log output]

So it looks like it's safe to call an async method without waiting, as long as the entire ASP.NET process doesn't crash.