# C# Fire and Forget Task and discard

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, c#-7.0

I need to do a fire and forget call to some async method. I realised VS is suggesting that I can set the call to a _discard and the IDE warning goes away. But I'm not sure if that call is still not awaited when used with the discard. Would it be?

```
 public async Task<object> SomeSideTaskToBeForgotten()
 {
     ...blah blah
 }

 public async Task MainTask()
 {
     ..some stuff
     _ = SomeSideTaskToBeForgotten(); //is this still fire and forget?
     ..some other stuff
 }
```

Comment: The `_` will discard the returned Task without awaiting it's completion. `_ = await SomeSideTaskToBeForgotten();` would await the Task and then discard the result

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22629951/1768303

Comment: Just remember that "fire and forget" means "I don't care if this succeeds".

Comment: @GabrielLuci no worries, I actually don't care if it fails and the result of the task is not important as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it's still fire and forget.

When `SomeSideTaskToBeForgotten();` returns a `Task`, the remainder of your method will execute, without waiting for the `Task` to complete.

The discard just makes explicit the fact that the `Task` isn't required for any further processing.

VS suggests the discard because `SomeSideTaskToBeForgotten();` returns something i.e. not void, but adding the discard also suppresses the warning, because it informs the compiler that an await hasn't been omitted accidentally.

Comment: I think there is a miscomprehension here. Await doesn't get skipped once the task is over; it hands over control to the calling function until the awaited task returns, until which execution continues statements after the await.

Comment: @Denis What `await`? There is no `await` in the OP's code.