# How should completion of non-awaited tasks be detected?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

In a different question I posted this code snippet:

```
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            //Monitor services TCP messages to this client
            var monitor = new My.Monitor(client);
            _ = monitor.MonitorAsync(cancellation.Token);
        }
```

I excplicitly do not want to `await` on `MonitorAsync` - this code is spooling up new connections to multiple clients.

This leads to 'ophaned' tasks - if `MonitorAsync` throws, we are not going to notice or be able to respond. We don't know it has completed at all.

`Monitor` instances are going to be continually created and disposed as client sessions start and end. Likely they would be stored in a collection:

```
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        //Monitor services TCP messages to this client
        var monitor = new Monitor(client);
        monitorTasks.Add(monitor.MonitorAsync(cancellation.Token));
    }
```

But since the collection will have elements added and removed often, I am pretty sure `Task.WhenAny(monitorTasks)` is not suitable?

The only other idea I can consider is using `ContinueWith` e.g.:

```
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        //Monitor services TCP messages to this client
        var monitor = new Monitor(client);
        _ = monitor.MonitorAsync(cancellation.Token).ContinueWith(() => MonitoringFinished(monitor));
    }
```

Is either of these a good solution or does TPL provide something nicer? It must be fairly common to have "fire and forget" task parallelism but still track failures.

Comment: One (of many) options: you can surround the code in `MonitorAsync` with a try/catch block.

Comment: That somewhat crudely handles failure cases but what about knowing when it completes? We could get into call-backs but would a continuation be the neat approach?

Comment: Isn't it enough for the `Monitor` class to know internally which and when a monitoring operation has failed, and act accordingly, for example by logging the exception? Why involve the caller at all? What kind of code could be inside the `MonitoringFinished` continuation?

Comment: One thought @TheodorZoulias is should we trust `Monitor` to catch any exception? Is that good practice? I'm not sure. I'm not hugely upset with the first version, but it was suggested fire-and-forget was a bad practice so I thought I'd see if there are any standard ways of dealing with this pattern

Comment: If you don't trust the `Monitor` to handle its internal errors, why would you trust it to propagate them correctly to the caller? A buggy `Monitor` could easily hand to the caller never-ending tasks (`return new TaskCompletionSource<bool>().Task`), or tasks faulted with an exception completely unrelated to the original error (like for example errors thrown from inside its catch block, related to buggy logging logic). I'd say make your best effort to make the `Monitor` as bug-free as possible, instead of trying to handle the same errors in multiple layers.

Comment: The entire point of exception handling is to handle exceptional behaviour. Unless `MonitorAsync` has a big `try{...}catch(Exception){...}` - which is a bad idea IMO - you don't know an array indexing or null reference won't sneak through. An exception that is never seen is dangerous. But maybe I misunderstand your point @TheodorZoulias

Comment: So the idea is to put logging code inside the `MonitoringFinished` continuation, so that any exceptional behavior related to the asynchronous `MonitorAsync` method can be logged?

Answer (score 1):

There are several other options that haven't been mentioned by the OP: `Task.Run`, `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`, `RaiseError extension`. etc.

#### Task.Run

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
   //Your fire and forget action call 
}).ContinueWith((task) =>
{
   if (task.IsFaulted) throw task.Exception; //not the best because of rethrow
   //if (task.IsCompleted) { // do some extra stuff if needed };
});
```

Obviously it can be further optimized with the use of `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`.

#### UnobservedTaskException

To enable the feature

```
<runtime> 
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
</runtime>
```

To subscribe

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => {
    e.SetObserved();
    throw e.Exception; 
 };
```

The problem with this approach that this event is only fired when the Task is finalized. Which may or may not be a problem in your case

#### Forget extension

It is just an alternative to the continueWith

```
public static void RaiseError(this Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        _ = RaiseError(task);
    }

    async static Task RaiseError(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            // do some extra stuff if needed 
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm probably thinking `ContinueWith` would be used to notify the calling class - so this object can be cleared up or at least a log entry made.