# Async task memory leak

Tags: c#, asynchronous, memory-leaks, uwp

I'm just profiling a UWP application running on a device trying to diagnose an observed memory leak.

Using snapshots, I've observed that I have a growing number of Task objects, which seem to be created from an internal component which raises logging events.

Here is a screenshot of a compared snapshot and the object that appears to be leaking.

[image: Memory snapshot]
[image: Path to root]

I have two event listeners bound to OnLogReceived; they look like this:

```
ApplicationContext.Current.LoggerContext.OnLogReceived += LoggerContext_OnLogReceived;
ApplicationContext.Current.LoggerContext.OnLogReceived += (logLevel, timestamp, message) => RemoteLogHelper.SendMessage(logLevel, message);
```

Here is the definition of first handler. This displays the log in a scrolling viewer on the screen and truncates the entries to 1000. The LogEntryModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged via ViewModelBase to avoid leaking  PropertyChanged.

```
private async void LoggerContext_OnLogReceived(LogLevel logLevel, DateTime timestamp, string message)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            var entry = new LogEntryModel
            {
                Message = string.Format("[{0:h:mm:ss tt}] {1}", timestamp, message)
            };
            entry.SetDispatcher(ApplicationContext.Current.Dispatcher);

            lock (ApplicationContext.Current.ReceiverDetails.Log)
            {
                ApplicationContext.Current.ReceiverDetails.Log.Add(entry);

                while (ApplicationContext.Current.ReceiverDetails.Log.Count > 1000)
                {
                    ApplicationContext.Current.ReceiverDetails.Log.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            if (!uxPreventLogFromScrolling.IsChecked ?? false)
            {
                LogScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0d, double.MaxValue, 1.0f);
            }
        });
    }
```

And the send message handler (2)
This sends the log lines to a remote API (if remote logging is enabled for this device) for debugging purposes. We want this to be fire & forget, meaning we don't want to wait around for the log to be successfully sent to the endpoint.

```
public static async void SendMessage(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled())
            return;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                ApplicationContext.Current.ApiClient.PostAsync<LogRequestModel, object>("/api/remote/receiver/log", new LogRequestModel { MacAddress = MacAddress, Text = message });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ; // we tried
            }
        });
    }
```

Changing this method to the following definition does not change the behavour (still showing a similar snapshot result)

```
public static async void SendMessage(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled())
            return;

        try
        {
            await ApplicationContext.Current.ApiClient.PostAsync<LogRequestModel, object>("/api/remote/receiver/log", new LogRequestModel { MacAddress = MacAddress, Text = message });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ; // we tried
        }

    }
```

Can anyone pinpoint why this is leaking and how I avoid it? 
From research, I don't think I need to dispose the tasks and everything here looks like it should be getting cleaned up automatically on completion.
However I can definitly see the memory usage growing and the snapshots confirm this.

Comment: I would suggest using a memory profiler that can trace the instances of `Task` back to a GC root.  Something is holding a reference to them and you need to find out what that is.

Comment: It would seem that those tasks are being blocked at the locking mechanism, preventing them from being disposed. I think the likely culprit is a deadlock in the LoggerContext_OnLogReceived. A peculiar line of code sticks out to me in the SendMessage method as well as ApiClient.PostAsync says it is asynchronous, yet it's being ran in a Task.Run() call. Does this method not return a Task? If it does and it's executing a hot task, I'm not sure how Task.Run handles that as it's expecting the work to actually finish.

Comment: @Zer0 the screengrab of snapshot appears to show the path to root for that Task<VoidValueTypeParameter> if that helps

Comment: @DavidY the ApiClient.PostAsync does indeed return Task<object> (but it's intentionally not awaited). This block was my most likely culprit too, but I am not sure how to call an async method which I don't care for the result of. The snapshot seems to indicate it is a Task<void> that is leaking though.

Comment: @Zer0 I have added an additional screenshot showing the full path to root for the object that appears to be leaking

Comment: You can still await the Task even though you don't care about the result. Give that a try.

Comment: @DavidY am I right in assuming that if I await it, then it becomes blocking and the call to SendMessage will block until the PostAsync method completes (which is calling a remote API so can be slow)?

Comment: @agrath Yes, an `await` will change functionality significantly.  The method that uses `await` will not continue until the `Task` completes.

Comment: @agrath I do see the path now - just used to a more clear visual graph myself.  Should be all the info you need to resolve the leak.  It's literally showing you what is holding the references.  I also agree with DavidY.  Are you sure these tasks are completing?  Worth looking into.  You could add a continuation to these tasks to see if they are completing correctly.

Comment: @DavidY No dice, i've updated the question with the replaced function body for SendMessage (removing the additional Task.Run and await'ing PostAsync)

Comment: `ApplicationContext` is NOT supported in UWP app, yet you're saying that you're developing an UWP app. Assume that you've create a class named this and seems like you put some static method inside it, but with `HttpClient` for `PostAsync`, there could be possibilities which can cause memory leaks due to different reasons. Since you've narrowed down to your `SendMessage`, I suggest that wrapping your `PostAsync` with `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documenting the answer here in case someone else runs into this.
We used .ContinueWith to prevent leaking the task

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15524271/647728

```
    public static void SendMessage(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled())
            return;

        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/15524271/647728
        ApplicationContext.Current.ApiClient.PostAsync<LogRequestModel, object>("/api/remote/receiver/log", new LogRequestModel { MacAddress = MacAddress, Text = message }).ContinueWith(t => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    }
```

}

Comment: I don't quite understand why your 2nd SendMessage above was leaking. I thought `await` would unroll the exceptions to be caught properly. What am I missing?

Comment: @JoePhillips neither. We never got to the bottom of _why_ it leaked, only that it did, until we used ContinueWith to ensure completion of the task