# Visual Studio App Center: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monogame, visual-studio-app-center

I need help with App Center push notifications. I want to find out if the user has enabled or disabled push notifications on his iOS/Android device. This task should be done when the application launches. I followed this App Center tutorial but I get an error message when I check if push notifications are enabled or disabled.

[App Center tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios)

> Error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async
>   method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and
>   changing its return type to 'Task'.

What is wrong? How can I find out if the user has enabled or disabled push notifications?

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Push;

namespace iosprojectnew.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    class Program : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        private static Game1 game;

        internal static void RunGame()
        {
            game = new Game1();
            game.Run();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }

        public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app)
        {      
            if (!AppCenter.Configured)
            {
                bool isEnabled = await Push.IsEnabledAsync();

                Push.PushNotificationReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // Add the notification message and title to the message
                    var summary = $"Push notification received:" +
                                        $"\n\tNotification title: {e.Title}" +
                                        $"\n\tMessage: {e.Message}";

                    // If there is custom data associated with the notification,
                    // print the entries
                    if (e.CustomData != null)
                    {
                        summary += "\n\tCustom data:\n";
                        foreach (var key in e.CustomData.Keys)
                        {
                            summary += $"\t\t{key} : {e.CustomData[key]}\n";
                        }
                    }

                    // Send the notification summary to debug output
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(summary);
                };
            }


            AppCenter.Start("...", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Push));
            RunGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to safely call an async method in C# without await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522900/how-to-safely-call-an-async-method-in-c-sharp-without-await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method that uses `await` must be marked as `async`. Try to add the `async` keyword before `void FinishedLaunching`:

```
public override async void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The await keyword can be used only into a async method, but this method is an override, so you cant' transform to a task.

Anyway you can write the line code where you use async like this:

```
bool isEnabled = await Push.IsEnabledAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Blocking on async code is generally considered as a bad practice and may lead to deadlocks.